# How to copy data between 2 delimiters from a C string?

Tags: c

I am trying to copy the characters from `str` that lay in between the `:` and `e` characters.

I have `char str[] = "192.169.0.1:12345e";`
I am able to copy data before the ':' using `strrchr()`, but
how can I copy the `12345` characters that lie between the `:` and `e`?

Comment: Is this code C or C++? Pick one, since the languages are different (like, why are you not using `std::string`).

Comment: Find the start, find the end, memcpy?

Comment: @JonathanPotter but how to put adress range in the memcpy ?

Comment: `char nums[16];sscanf(str, "%*[^:]:%15[^e]", nums);`

Comment: You can use strrchr (or strchr) to find the positions of the ':' and 'e', and then use strncpy to copy that part.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to parse an IP address with a port. If so, why not use:

```
char str[] = "192.169.0.1:12345e";
unsigned char ipAddress[4];
unsigned short int port;

if (sscanf(str, "%hhu.%hhu.%hhu.%hhu:%hu"
    , &ipAddress[0]
    , &ipAddress[1]
    , &ipAddress[2]
    , &ipAddress[3]
    , &port) >= 5)
{
    // use the data...
}
```

Comment: I upvoted this, since it seems to address the real problem ;). However, I think you should compare the return value of the sscanf for equality with 5 and not test if it is larger than 5 because that looks silly :p. If it would return 6 (which is impossible) then I'd be even more alarmed than when it returned 4 :p.

Comment: @CarloWood Honestly I'd chalk it up to coding style. The way I think is: something went wrong if it's less than 5. Not less than 5 means greater than or equal to 5, in which (favorable) case I will encapsulate in the `if` and be merrily along my way. [In a world where a return value of 6 becomes possible](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/i-dont-want-to-live-on-this-planet-anymore), I would no longer trust a return value of 5 either.

Answer (score 0):

It depende on the logic. For example what to do if character 'e' is not found?

The code could look for example the following way

```
if ( char *p = strchr( str, ':' ) )
{
   while ( *++p != 'e' && *p != '\0' ) *buffer++ = *p;
   *buffer = '\0';
}
```

Or

```
char *p, *q;

if ( ( p = strchr( str, ':' ) ) && ( q = strchr( p, 'e' ) ) )
{
   while ( ++p != q ) *buffer++ = *p;
   *buffer = '\0';
}
```

Instead of `strchr` you can use `strrchr`